# Accidentally under-clocked the CPU, and now I don’t know how to go back

Tags: overclocking, intel-core-i7, underclock

My system boots fine. It’s just that I underclocked it instead of overclocking.

First time overclocking!

Now for the important stuff. I have an Intel i7 6700k. My motherboard is an Asus Z170-E. If you didn't get it before, I tried overclocking, but screwed up. How bad? This bad:

- CPU Default clock: 4.00 GHz
- My supposed “overclock”: 3.00 GHz

I don’t even know what I did!

I thought I changed back the only setting I touched in my BIOS after noticing the 3.00 GHz, but it didn't change. I can’t remember setting name.

**Should I reset to default BIOS settings?** That would be a pain since I have four hard drives and boot order related stuff.

**Is there a way to go back without defaulting?** Probably not since I’ not much help here since I don’t even know what setting I changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I fixed it by fixing the BCLK (base clock) value!

It turns out I had changed the BCLK and while keeping the min/max CPU Cache ratios at *Auto*.

Before the switch, my system was 4.00 GHz. After, it was 3.00 GHz. This was my first time overclocking, so I learned quite a bit!

My goal was 4.3 GHz. After learning what BCLK actually *was*, I changed its value to *102.38*. Then, I changed my min/max CPU Cache ratio to 42. That successfully got me to 4.3 GHz!

#### For those wanting to know how to get to a certain clock for the first time, here are some helpful tips.

- The clock you want to reach will be 'C'. BCLK (known as Base Clock) will be 'b'. The min/max CPU Cache ratio (this is our multiplier) will be 'm'.
- The equation is `b * m = C`. So, play around with the numbers in a calculator and see what you need to reach your desired clock. So, for me, 102.38 * 42 MHz = ~4300 MHz.

1 GHz = 1000 MHz. and, in turn, 102.38 MHz multiplied by 42 is 4300 MHz, which is 4.3 GHz.

Answer (score -2):

You do not want to reset to default settings because of the boot order? Well, simply check the current boot order, write it down, reset to defaults and then simply put it back in again.

Answer (score -2):

Just reset the BIOS and fix the boot order. It only takes like 15 seconds.

Also for overclocking, high numbers tend to relate to a higher overclock. If you want to OC up the multiplayer.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence? Can you elaborate?